# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_17 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (8, 4800000)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Hi everyone I must implement a cnn + lstm model and I've this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_17 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (8, 4800000)
```

this is my code with:

```
X_train.shape = (8, 4800000, 1)
y_train_arousal.shape=(8, 4800000).
```

X_train are 8 audio tracks, 4800000 are the samples and 1 channel

y_train_arousal: for each audio track and for each sample correspond to an arousal value.

So my model reads sequentially the samples and for each sample produces 1 value, I must evaluate the variance between the output value vary with the sample

```
model_arousal = Sequential()

model_arousal.add(Conv1D(filters=40, kernel_size=40, strides=2, activation='tanh', input_shape=(4800000, 1)))
model_arousal.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model_arousal.add(Dropout(0.5))

model_arousal.add(Conv1D(filters=40, kernel_size=400, strides=2, activation='tanh'))
model_arousal.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=20))
model_arousal.add(Dropout(0.5))

model_arousal.add(LSTM(128, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))
model_arousal.add(LSTM(128, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))

model_arousal.add(Flatten())
model_arousal.add(Dense(2))

adam = Adam(0.002)
model_arousal.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
model_arousal.summary()


_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_47 (Conv1D)           (None, 2399981, 40)       1640      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_42 (MaxPooling (None, 1199990, 40)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_39 (Dropout)         (None, 1199990, 40)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_48 (Conv1D)           (None, 599796, 40)        640040    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_43 (MaxPooling (None, 29989, 40)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_40 (Dropout)         (None, 29989, 40)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_19 (LSTM)               (None, 29989, 128)        86528     
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_20 (LSTM)               (None, 29989, 128)        131584    
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_19 (Flatten)         (None, 3838592)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_17 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 3838593   
=================================================================
Total params: 4,698,385
Trainable params: 4,698,385
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________

h = model_arousal.fit(X_train, y_train_arousal, batch_size=50, epochs=5, verbose=1)
```

UPDATE

I'm trying to explain myself as clear as I can be.

For simplicity I consider just one audio track. For each sample of the track correspond an arousal value.
So my network must predict for each sample an arousal value, then compare it with the corresponding arousal value for the sample-ith

Comment: Please give more information about your data. What are your inputs and expected output? 8 tracks, x samples and channels does not define your inputs. Talking about just your problem: you have one output neuron and you are comparing it with 4800000 neurons

Comment: I expanded the dimension because Conv1D require a 3-dimension array.
So I need comparing the output value of each sample of each track qith the y value of each sample of each track

Comment: That means you have 1 input and 1 output. Is that right?

Comment: yes, for each sample the network will produces 1 value. This results will be compared with the value of y

Comment: Well if you have just 1 input, what will a CNN or anything else will learn? I think your problem is a time-series problem. Read about it and tell me if your problem is a similar one

Comment: I think that I must reshape the input like this (8,1,4800000) so for each track audio, I get 1 time series which include 4800000. But how can I change the input_shape for the conv?

Comment: maybe this could help https://ibug.doc.ic.ac.uk/media/uploads/documents/learning_audio_paralinguistics_from_the_raw_waveform.pdf